# How to expose a method to rest service?

Tags: java, rest, http-post, ejb

I'm new on Rest I just need help with a couple of things here. I need help with exposing a method inside an EJB to REST. The method below is inside an EJB, I just need to use POST to "rest-ify" this method.

```
public Boolean lockUnlockForecastForCustomer(Long businessEntityPK, Long customerPK, Date currentDate,
                                             Long lockAction, String userid) {
    log.info("Lock/Unlock Forecast for Customer: BE ID" + customerPK + "- Current Date" + currentDate);

    // log.info("Checking Lock Action - Action is: " + lockAction);
    if (lockAction == 1) {
        log.info("Unlocking...");
    } else if (lockAction == 3) {
        log.info("Locking...");
    }

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    Integer ret = 0;
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = con
                .prepareStatement("update transactional.CUST_SUBMISSION set LASTTOUCHEDUSER = ?, LASTTOUCHED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SUBMISSIONSTATUS_PK = ?,FORECASTSUBMISSIONSTATUS_PK = ?,INVENTORYSUBMISSIONSTATUS_PK = ?,SALESUBMISSIONSTATUS_PK = ? where CUSTOMER_PK = ? and PLANNINGCALENDAR_PK in (select PLANNINGCALENDAR_PK from master.PLANNINGCAL where BUSINESSENTITY_PK = ? and STARTDATE <= CURRENT_DATE and ENDDATE >= CURRENT_DATE)");

        stmt.setString(1, userid);
        stmt.setLong(2, lockAction);
        stmt.setLong(3, lockAction);
        stmt.setLong(4, lockAction);
        stmt.setLong(5, lockAction);
        stmt.setLong(6, customerPK);
        stmt.setLong(7, businessEntityPK);


        ret = stmt.executeUpdate();
        success = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

So far I have created a new Rest class and a method below which is not complete, so basically this is where I'm stuck.

```
@POST
@Path("/lockUnlockCustomer")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response lockUnlockForecastForCustomer(Long businessEntityPK, Long customerPK, Date currentDate,Long lockAction, String userid)
{
    siteLockEJB = new SiteLockEJB();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: Since you're using EJBs you're probably running inside a JavaEE environment. In that case have a look at jax-rs or JSR 181. You basically can "restify" an ejb (maybe create a separate one though) via annotations like `@WebService` etc.

Comment: Exactly what I want to do. Check the code below, I want to do the same with that method. ` @Path("/echo")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response sayHello()
    {
        return Response.ok("I said Echo").build();
    } `

Comment: With simpathy, you cannot ask a question about EJB when you have a statement like this in your code: `siteLockEJB = new SiteLockEJB();` I hope it's a typo error, otherwise you are just missing the basic staff :-)

Comment: @Leonardo, I'm almost clueless on this stuff. I'm making my code work from another code.